# On starting sssd

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd

there.

At first, it says the daemon couldn't find the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf. So, I created this and, when executing sssd "systemctl start sssd.service", it shows the following errors.

```
Jun 25 21:00:48 tmax1 sssd[nss][14286]: Starting up
Jun 25 21:00:48 tmax1 sssd[nss][14288]: Starting up
Jun 25 21:00:48 tmax1 sssd[pam][14287]: Starting up
Jun 25 21:00:48 tmax1 sssd[pam][14289]: Starting up
Jun 25 21:00:49 tmax1 sssd[be[DOMAIN.COM]][14290]: Starting up
Jun 25 21:00:49 tmax1 sssd[14278]: Exiting the SSSD. Could not restart critical service [DOMAIN.COM].
Jun 25 21:00:49 tmax1 systemd[1]: sssd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 25 21:00:49 tmax1 systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
Jun 25 21:00:49 tmax1 systemd[1]: Unit sssd.service entered failed state.
Jun 25 21:00:49 tmax1 systemd[1]: sssd.service failed.
```

Is there any other configuration file or something to check before running sssd?

I can check the realm by "realm discover DOMAIN.COM". Ping is fine.

```
[test1@ ~]$ realm discover domain.com
domain.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: DOMAIN.COM
  domain-name: domain.com
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-tools
```

Sometimes, the "kinit" command doesn't work, but I can see the ticket by the "klist" only with the root account.

```
[test1@ ~]$ klist
klist: Credentials cache keyring 'persistent:1000:1000' not found

[root@ ~]# klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:0
Default principal: administrator@DOMAIN.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/25/2018 17:08:47  06/26/2018 03:08:47  krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM
    renew until 07/02/2018 17:08:45
```

What do I do more to start sssd..?

Thank you.

Comment: Same as [for your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451028/100397). Stop overthinking the problem. Join to the domain first.

Comment: Alright, I'll focus on "realm" first, not "sssd". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following on the server:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mountd
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind
firewall-cmd --reload
```

then restart nfs on the server:

```
systemctl restart nfs
```

then export:

```
exportfs -avf
```