# About PAM authentication using sssd

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd

there.

I succeed to join Linux environment to Windows Server domain, using realm join command. (Thanks Roaima) [From this Stack ticket.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451028/connecting-to-active-directory-with-winbind)

Now the next step seems to authenticate to Active Directory.
So, I guess I have to configure some files, for example,

1. /etc/pam.d/system-auth
2. /etc/pam.d/password-auth
3. /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

Finally, if I can succeed to find  a user with the "id" command, then I can use PAM for authentication to Windows Active Directory, right??

However, I can't get the authentication from Windows server for a reason I don't know..

```
[root@ /]# realm list
domain.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: DOMAIN.COM
  domain-name: domain.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-tools
  login-formats: %U@domain.com
  login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
  permitted-logins: administrator@domain.com
  permitted-groups: 

[root@ /]# id administrator@test1.domain.com
id: administrator@test1.domain.com: no such user
```

Do I need to configure the above files??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wish some of people who face the same issue to be helped with this.

Check the Windows Server version first. My one is 2012 and its unix attribute configuration is DEPRECATED. So, this feature is needed to be opened by the program "Dism.exe".. Just find this command in Google and execute it by following. Very easy.

If one of you guys succeeded to join the Active Directory realm, then it means you have to check AD first.

Thanks all make me helped.